# What is the best way to safely process a login using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular. I'm developing a simple login form whereby the username typed is compared to a username returned from a JSON query. If a match is found, the login is processed.

I feel the way I'm doing it isn't safe, am I right in thinking that the returned JSON string could be accessed through the browser's console?

I will be adding password check to this as well in the near future, once I understand how to properly go about this.

I would like pointing in the right direction to approach the issue of user login the Angular way.

**app.js**

```
angular.module('userApp', ["ngResource"]).

config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',   controller: LoginCtrl}).
        when('/loggedin', {templateUrl: 'partials/user-admin.html', controller: UserCtrl}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
}],[ '$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode = true;
}]).

factory("User", function($resource) {
    return $resource("users/:userId.json", {}, {
        query: {method: "GET", params: {userId: "users"}, isArray: true}
    });
});
```

**controllers.js**

```
function LoginCtrl($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, User) {
    $scope.users = User.query();
    $scope.loginUser = function() {
        var loggedin = false;
        var totalUsers = $scope.users.length;
        var usernameTyped = $scope.userUsername;

        for( i=0; i < totalUsers; i++ ) {
            if( $scope.users[i].name === usernameTyped ) {
                loggedin = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if( loggedin === true ) {
            alert("login successful");
            $location.path("/loggedin");
        } else {
            alert("username does not exist")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do your checking on the server side, not the client side

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you are right - **this is not safe**. NEVER do such things:

- NEVER store plain passwords in database (like "my_password_123"
- NEVER return any sort of sensitive information to the client and perform secret computations in JavaScript
- NEVER use simple password comparison (`providedPassword == stored password`) in server or client code
- NEVER use unsecure (http) layer - use safe one (HTTPS) instead

A proper way of doing this is following:

1. Generate Hashed value of password on store it in DB. Make sure to use a strong hashing algorithm and salted passwords. At the time of writing this reply SHA-256 would be enough, but make sure to check if it's still considered safe.
2. Wire SSL certificate to get HTTPS support, that way noone will spy on what user sends to your server
3. User enters `username+password` and sends them to your code on the server. **On the server** you compute SHA-1 hash and compare it against the stored value in DB. Then you send back the RESULT of authentication to the client and keep the track of it on the server by persistent session.

Please keep in mind that most of this stuff is done by some security frameworks, like [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/). I wouldn't recommend doing it all from scratch, as the topic of security is vast and it's easy to make a mistake that can be used by malicious users.

Comment: Nice summary, but what's actually the reason to compute the hash on the server? If the hash would be client site created it would be even more secure when some one gets into your ssl connection. Right?

Comment: Well, depends on how you compute hashes. Here I mentioned that the password might be salted. This salt is usually not known to the client.
Generally speaking you are right, that it all fails if someone breaks your SSL connection, but if that happens you are tosted either way.

Comment: I would not recommend SHA-1. It hasn't been considered secure for a long time. Rather recommend SHA-256. The title of this question is such that a lot of people will end up looking at this answer, so I think it's worth updating the recommended algorithm.

Comment: In case someone needs a lib for the SHA256: https://github.com/emn178/js-sha256 :)