# How to encrypt the Login credentials in angularjs project?

Tags: security, authentication, https

In my angularjs project, I am making an ajax call to a third party server to check user login. I am not using **HTTPS**. I want to encrypt the login credentials. Which would be the best way to do so.

Comment: Which mechanisms does "a third party server" provide/support?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754998/what-is-the-best-way-to-safely-process-a-login-using-angularjs

Comment: related: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53594/why-is-client-side-hashing-of-a-password-so-uncommon

Comment: I am using Jetty server which is not configured to HTTPS.

Comment: So the "third party server" is actually under your control?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a reverse proxy on your web server and store the credentials there.